# Cross Tab Query with filtered maximum Value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following Crosstab query code for the following table(VWDRSSTA)

```
SYSTEM  EREIGNIS    DATUM_ZEIT  ANTRAGSNUMMER   DUNKEL
   VS    POL_AN      1.1.2016      123            1
   VS    ANL_SW      1.2.2016      123            0
   ZW    EIN_ED      1.3.2016      123            0
   ZW    AUS_ED      1.4.2016      222            1
   VS    POL_AN      1.5.2016      222            0
   VS    ANL_SW      1.6.2016      222            0
```

*Crosstab query code*

```
TRANSFORM Max(VWDRSSTA.DATUM_ZEIT) AS MaxOfDATUM_ZEIT
SELECT VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER,
    Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL) AS Dunkel,
    FROM VWDRSSTA
INNER JOIN V_NAMES ON (VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = V_NAMES.SYSTEM_CODE)
    AND (VWDRSSTA.EREIGNIS = V_NAMES.EREIGNIS)
GROUP BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
ORDER BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
PIVOT V_NAMES.MAPPED_NAME;
```

where `V_Names` is a lookup table with names to be mapped.

which gives me the result

```
ANTRAGSNUMMER   DUNKEL    Eingang       Ausgang    Schwebe   Policierung
   123            1       1.3.2016                 1.2.2016   1.1.2016
   222            1                     1.4.2016   1.6.2016   1.5.2016
```

Since the above code uses `Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL) AS Dunkel` I get the maximum as 1 for both the `Antragsnummer` where in I want the `DUNKEL` value to be the maximum of the VS in system field. So technically I want the 2nd record with `Antragsnummer` 222 to be shown as

```
222            0                     1.4.2016   1.6.2016   1.5.2016
```

Till now I have substituted the `Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL) AS Dunkel` with

```
DMax("DUNKEL","VWDRSSTA","SYSTEM ='VS'") AS Dunkel
```

and

```
IF(VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = 'VS', (
            SELECT (Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL)) AS d
            FROM VWDRSSTA
            ), NULL) AS Dunkel
```

but both of them do not work as expected. For the latter one I got the following error

> Multi-level GROUP BY clause is not allowed in a sub query

And when I use DMax I get only 1 value which is the Maximum.

How can I achieve the above result?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the DMAX() but this can affect the performance on a larger table.

Consider this Query:

```
SELECT 
    outer_VWDRSSTA.antragsnummer,
    DMax("dunkel","VWDRSSTA","[system]='VS' AND antragsnummer =" & [outer_VWDRSSTA].[antragsnummer]) AS mdunkel
FROM VWDRSSTA AS outer_VWDRSSTA
GROUP BY outer_VWDRSSTA.antragsnummer;
```

will output:

```
+---------------+---------+
| antragsnummer | mdunkel |
+---------------+---------+
|           123 |       1 |
|           222 |       0 |
+---------------+---------+
```

you had:

```
DMax("DUNKEL","VWDRSSTA","SYSTEM ='VS'") AS Dunkel
```

this will get the max for VS regardless of which Antragsnummer it belongs to. Hence you got always 1